# Why use pandas fillna() in this instance

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking at this piece of code:

```
return (df[column].fillna('') == value).sum()
```

It checks to see how many times "value" occurs in a particular column. What's the purpose of using fillna in this instance? Why not, for example, just use the following code?

```
return (df[column] == value).sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably meant to avoid errors that may arise from adding nan and numeric values.

However, it may be best to do this by using the numeric_only flag in pandas' sum() method.

numeric_only : boolean, default None
Include only float, int, boolean data. If None, will attempt to use everything, then use only numeric data

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html